# Join 2 tables and create a new row showing if table 2 exists in table 1

Tags: mysql, database, join, null, case

I have this two tables

Table 1

```
+-----------+----------+
| support_id| Name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | Name 1   |
| 2         | Name 2   |
+-----------+----------+
```

Table 2

```
+-----------+----------+
| school_id | support_id|
+-----------+----------+
| 2314      | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
```

Desire output

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| school_id |support_id|     has    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2314      | 1        | Yes        |
| 2314      | 2        | No         |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

How can I add the third row telling me if table 2 is in table 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would the second row have school_id=2314? Where does this info come from?

Comment: It comes from another table named schools, Table 2 has both primary keys from table 1 the other schools table, but I pull my data from table 2 that's why I only put those 2 on the question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: If your `Table 1` also have `school_id` column, it would be much easier to do.

Comment: Can you please show your `schools` table as well? See if we can do something from it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a table1 "is" in table2?
The field support_id is the same as the support_id in table 2? 
Or the field or the school_id is the same?

You need a field to be the same in both tables in order to make a connection (Foreign Key), make a join and connect both tables.

Considering support_id to be the foreigh key (the value shared between both tables) you can use this select:

```
   SELECT school_id, IF(support_id is not null, "Yes", "No") as Has
   FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
   ON table1.support_id = table2.support_id;
```

Comment: Yes, support_id is in both tables and is a foreign key, I just tried your query and only get one column with  "2314 | 1 | Yes", but can't make the second one for "2314 | 2 | No" :(

Comment: There is something different your data then, I think you mean one Row correct? This select should return all values. For some reason the support_id may be different and not matching (maybe a space? different column type like int = varchar?) Also check if the data is correctly inserted in table2 and table1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a left join and then a `case` expression to format the results:

```
SELECT    t2.*, CASE WHEN t1.support_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM      t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.support_id = t1.support_id
```

Comment: Hello, I just did your query and it's only showing "2314 | 1 | Yes", but not for  "2314 | 2 | No" :(